# Где спрашивать перевод слова на английский?

Tags: support

Это сугубо русская фраза. Дословно переводися убого. Хочется литературного перевода. Спрашивать тут или в english.stackexchange (у них ещё ell.stackexchange есть)?

Where should I ask for Russian (idiomatic) phase translation to English: here or in english/ell.stackexchange? The word-by-word translation is ugly and will confuse the people rather than illustrate what I want to say.

Comment: Questions on Meta should be asked (or translated) in English: http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/a/111/551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что нужно спрашивать в english.SE - описать смысл и спросить, как лучше всего его выразить по-английски.

Comment: Ок, я обнаружил FAQ, который прямо заявляет что спрашивать перевод тут нельзя, http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/125. Непонятно только почему FAQ запрятан в мета, а не в меню help сайта.